# Accessing a C++ static variable from gcc inline asm

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, gcc

For some reason I want to mix a bit of assembly with C++ (not C).
To allow the code to be compilable using the standard Arduino IDE, I don't want to use direct assembly source.
I don't want to use a wrapper C file either.

My problem is as follows:

I have a class with a single instance (implementing some kind of driver) that looks like this:

```
class cDriver {
public:
    char ISR_param;
    // ...
};

cDriver Driver;
```

If I want to access the `ISR_param` of this single instance from within an ISR, I can do something like:

```
ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_Vect) {
    do_something_with (Driver.ISR_param);
}
```

This works like a charm: the address of `Driver.ISR_param` beign a constant, the compiler simply generates an `lds r24, &Driver.ISR_param` instruction to load the proper byte as a parameter for `do_something_with`.

Now when I try to replicate the same mechanism with inline assembler, things get a lot more complicated.

The address of `Driver.ISR_param` is only known to the C++ compiler as an mangled label, and I can't find a way to pass it to the inline assembler to generate the equivalent `lds r24, <&Driver.ISR_param>`.

## trying to remane the variable

The renaming of variables for assembly like so:

```
char global_var asm("my_var");
```

and an attempt to use it like so:

```
asm ("lds r24, my_var\n");
```

will compile, but produce a linker error (`my_var` is undefined).

Looking at the object symbol table, the only label for `global_var` is a C++-like mangled name.
However hard I tried this renaming trick, I could not bring the compiler to generate a `my_var` label.

## trying to use asm constraints

A constraint like

```
asm (lds r24, %0\n" : : "I"(&global_var));
```

will simply not compile. I scoured the possible parameter types and could not find a way to let the assembler know about this bloody address.

## a terribly awkward workaround

The only way I found to make the compiler generate this dreaded `lds r24,...` instruction is to perform an actual function call.

So you can do something like:

```
__attribute__((always_inline)) give_me_my_friggin_variable(char data)
{
    asm volatile ("cmp  %0,%0\n"::"r"(data));
}   

ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_Vect, ISR_NAKED) {

    <some prologue to save SREG and all needed registers>

    //...

    give_me_my_friggin_variable(Driver.ISR_param);

    // continue assembly code with r24 properly initialized
}
```

That will generate:

```
    lds r24, <the proper address> // added by the compiler...
    cmp r24,r24                   // ...because of the register constraint here
```

Well, that sort of works, but at the cost of generating a totally useless instruction.

## so my question is...

Is there a simpler way to let the assembler know about addresses of C++ static variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
asm volatile("lds r24, %0" : : "i" (&Driver.ISR_param));
```

The `"i"` constraint means you provide an integer constant. It can be
any integer, unlike the uppercase `"I"` constraint which is limited to
6-bit positive integers.

**Addendum**:
The constraints supported by gcc are listed in the gcc documentation,
section [Constraints for `asm` Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html):

- The `"i"` constraint is listed in the subsection “Simple Constraints”
  and is described as:

> An immediate integer operand (one with constant value) is allowed.
>   This includes symbolic constants whose values will be known only at
>   assembly time or later.

- The `"I"` constraint is in the subsection “Machine Constraints” and,
  for the AVR architecture, is defined as

> Constant greater than -1, less than 64.

Comment: Dang... And thanks :). This "i" type was not listed in the online manuals I found. For completeness, could you add a link to an up to date documentation? Btw. I wonder why an example of such an obvious use of the inline assembler is so hard to come by.

Comment: @kuroineko: The `"i"` constraint is indeed missing from the avr-libc's [Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html). I added a link to the gcc documentation that lists it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That sort of cooking is pretty confidential I guess :).

Comment: The `"i"` constraint **does not mean "integer"**. `"i"` specifies an immediate operand, which is the union of `"n"` (integral operand known at compile-time) and `"s"` symbolic operand known at link time. For example, addresses of variables in static storage are known at link time, thus `"i"` will work for them.